# Add margin at top of webView in Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am downloading files from server and showing in my ios device. File type can be any thing like image, pdf etc. and all loading up fine. Now the problem is, some part of file or image is hiding behind the title of page. I want to add margin at top of file after it loads up.

Code I have written to show file:

```
func openFile(file:String) {
    let myBlog = file
    let url = NSURL(string: myBlog)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    webView.load(request as URLRequest)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    let pdfVC = UIViewController()
    pdfVC.view.addSubview(webView)
    pdfVC.title = "File"
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pdfVC, animated: true)
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = colors.whiteColor
}
```

I have created webView property within Class like:

```
var webView : WKWebView!
```

And inside viewDidLoad(), I have written:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Result I am getting:

[image]

Here some part of image is behind the title. I have tried verious solutions given in link [add margins in swift](https://blog.smartnsoft.com/layout-guide-margins-insets-and-safe-area-demystified-on-ios-10-11-d6e7246d7cb8), but nothing is working.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Where do you create this property? `webView `

Comment: @vpoltave I have updated question. This is inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create instance of `WKWebView` in controller where you need to display it, in your case instance `pdfVC`

There is can be model, for example:

```
enum FileType {
    case image(fileURL: URL)
    case pdf(fileURL: URL)
}
```

Creating incase of `FileViewController` and assign fileType to it

```
func openFile(file:String) {
    let pdfViewController = FileViewController()
    pdfVC.fileType = FileType.pdf(fileURL: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!) // example
    pdfVC.title = "File"
    navigationController?.pushViewController(pdfVC, animated: true)
}
```

> And inside your `VC` where you need to display a file:

In this way, even if you do have `navigationBar` you won't have problem with `navigationBar` and `topMargin`

```
class FileViewController: UIViewController {

    var fileType: FileType!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var urlRequest: URLRequest!
        switch fileType {
        case .image(let url), .pdf(let url):
            urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        @unknown default:
            break
        }

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
        self.view = webView
    }
}
```

**Hope this will help you!**

Answer (score 0):

use Bounds instead of Frame

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.Bounds)
```